# How to get depth of an image after its been converted to cv2 image?

Tags: python, opencv

[image]

As a staring point, an image was created using cv2, this is a black-white image.

```
self.depth = .... #numpy array with x,y = depth 
cv2.imwrite(self.depth)  #saved as jpg
```

Later in my code I need to convert back to get values of depth.

```
image  = cv2.imread(path)
        self.depth_array = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)
```

But in this array all values are between 0 or 255, while in self.depth array values were different, e.g. 10,3; 11,5; 18,5; etc.
Is it possible tO convert back cv2 image to get [x,y] array with depth values?

P.S.

I've recently tried code provided under, but it still gives me 0.0 and 255.0 values:

```
cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: Use `cv2.imread(..., cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)` if you want to read anything other than 8-bit data.

Comment: @Mark Setchell still all the values  I get are 255.

Comment: Please share your image, so we can see what you are trying to read - maybe use Dropbox or Google Drive if necessary.

Comment: @Mark Setchell updated with image

Comment: that's a JPEG. make sure to provide the original file. this site may or may not convert inserted pictures.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, that's .jpg image. since cv2 image was saved as type .jpg

Comment: then you've already lost information. JPEG can't carry more than 8 bits per channel. you've used the wrong file format.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz what image format should I use instead?

Comment: You can use TIFF or PFM or maybe EXR to save images made up of floats.

Comment: JPEG only stores 8 bit integers for each sample. PNG only stores 8..16 bit integers for each sample.